# SD card error for Arduino Mega

Tags: embedded, arduino

I am trying to run a simple program using a SD card module from spark fun with a Arduino Mega2560. This is the program i am current using:

```
#include <SD.h>

const int chipSelect = 10;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
  pinMode(53, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
  if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
    Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
    // don't do anything more:
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("card initialized.");
}

void loop()
{
  String dataString = "";

  for (int analogPin = 0; analogPin < 3; analogPin++) {
    int sensor = analogRead(analogPin);
    dataString += String(sensor);
    if (analogPin < 2) {
      dataString += ","; 
    }
  }

  File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);

  if (dataFile) {
    dataFile.println(dataString);
    dataFile.close();
    Serial.println(dataString);
  }  

  else {
    Serial.println("error opening datalog.txt");
  } 
}
```

The error i am receiving says :
Initializing SD card...Card failed, or not present
error opening datalog.txt

Comment: Do you have any independent confirmation that the wiring of the module to the Arduino is sound, and that the pins utilized are those the software expects (particularly for the select line)?  Have you accounted for difference between hardware SPI pins on a mega vs an uno?

Comment: This code works for Arduino Uno if i change the pinMode(53, OUTPUT); to pinMode(8, OUTPUT). However, when i try it for Mega2560 we had issues.

Comment: I only gave the docs a brief glance yesterday, but I believe the SPI pins may all be different between the two boards, so you may want to check that you really have the card wired to the correct pins on a mega.

Comment: So actually, i looked at the SPI pins for both the boards. For MEGA SPI: 50 (MISO), 51 (MOSI), 52 (SCK), 53 (SS) and for Uno SPI: 10 (SS), 11 (MOSI), 12 (MISO), 13 (SCK). My question is how would you connect it? do i have to make changes in the code or do i have to make changes in the hardware???? The thing is the sd card module sits on the whole arduino so how would i know which pin i have to connect if i had to with PIN 53???

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the Arduino Mega, but it sounds like that shield isn't really mega compatible.  Your options would be to not physically attach it, but only make electrical connections (or cut and modify the traces).  (Actually, if you make sure the pins the shield is connected to are set as inputs, you could simply add an additional flying-wire connection to the pins with the SPI signal you need).  Or else you can find or modify a sketch to use bit-bang SPI on arbitrary pins rather than the hardware SPI peripheral's pins, however this will be slower.

Comment: You might try reading the datasheet and the source code for the magic library.  98% of all Arduino questions stem from ignorance of the freely available documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
pinMode(53, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
```

To

```
pinMode(53, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(53, HIGH);
```

And have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it may happen for not writing this

```
File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);
```

immediately after this [or long before writing to that file]

```
Serial.println("card initialized.");
```

Believe me, this happened to me.